# JSON data parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, nspredicate

Need help in parsing JSON data with some conditions:

JSON data: https://api.myjson.com/bins/t1h7h

What i need to do is if user selects some date (key = date), i need "start_time" and "end_time" key values for that selected date in an array. Please note that same date is there in multiple dictionaries with different "start_time" and "end_time".

So for example if a user selects date as "20170225", i want to get all the "start_time" and "end_time" key values from dictionaries containing "date": "20170225".

I have the selected date in a variable.

I tried something with NSPredicate but i am stuck here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to convert all dates to `NSDate` using `NSDateFormatter` then you can apply a predicate. Generally *how* to parse JSON is one of the most frequent asked questions.

Comment: I have converted all dates to NSDate already but not able to apply predicate.

Comment: Please show the code you have written so far.

Comment: Can you show the NSPredicate code?

Comment: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.selectedDate LIKE[c] %@", listOfDates];

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionary *fetchDict = [self.arrayTimeline objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

```
    NSString *dateString = [fetchDict objectForKey:@"completion_time"];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[dateString doubleValue]];
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, YYYY"];
    NSString *datenewString = [format stringFromDate:date];
    cellprojectTimeline.lblCompletionTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", datenewString];}
```

Use this to convert into time or date, This will help you and working code.